# How to make `return TRUE` on successful input

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a registration form which validates the users email with JS and PHP and then checks the DB to see if the email exists. Everything happens on a single page with JSON.

I need the successful outcome to `RETURN TRUE` and take me to the next page in the registration sequence. I tried `window.location` under `case: success` and it takes me to the correct page however it doesn't carry over the hidden fields in my form.

Can someone give me an idea on how this should be executed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(){

    //check the form is not currently submitting
    if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){

        //setup variables
        var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
            responseMsg = $('#signup-response');

        //add status data to form
        form.data('formstatus','submitting');

        //show response message - waiting
        responseMsg.hide()
                   .addClass('response-waiting')
                   .text('Please Wait...')
                   .fadeIn(200);

        //send data to server for validation
        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            type: formMethod,
            data: formData,
            success:function(data){

                //setup variables
                var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                    klass = '';

                //response conditional
                switch(responseData.status){
                    case 'error':
                        klass = 'response-error';
                    break;
                    case 'success':
                        klass = 'response-success';
                        //return true; I tried this but it fails.
                    break;  
                }

                //show reponse message
                responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                           .addClass(klass)
                           .text(responseData.message)
                           .fadeIn(200,function(){
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function(){
                                   responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                       $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                       form.data('formstatus','idle');
                                   });
                               },3000)
                            });
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Ahem, how about NOT ajaxing? Instead submit the form and have the server return the next page with the fields filled in. Alternatively have the submit function copy in the new page with the fields

Comment: yeah i could do it with just php. but im trying to learn ajax.. i just like the UX aspect and perhaps so will my end user.. as a matter of fact i have non-JS version in full working order.. trying to make it snazzy for the folks who dont disable JS

Comment: If you already have a non-js method working, why not have the AJAX return the entire form and replace itself with what the usual page reload would return. Obviously to work in AJAX you'd have to only return what you'd normally echo in to the BODY tag. But after that all you'd need do is re-setup your event listeners again. This way you can pass back error highlighting and messages far more easily, and all your fields should have the correct values prewritten by php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just remove the submit handler on success and let the form submit for "real"?

Replace

```
//return true; I tried this but it fails.
```

With

```
$('#newsletter-signup').unbind('submit').submit();
```

Sidenote: returning whatever from a success callback does not make the form "do" anything else. The `return false;` statement have already been executed when the ajax function is complete. You need to resubmit the form again, this time without ajax.

Comment: You solution works as far as forwarding the page and checking if the email exists and ensuring !empty. However it not passing my `hidden` fields and instead of saying SUCCESSFUL, says email exists. It does however add the email to the DB -- I need to modify my PHP script for this work around - but this appears to be functioning. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

putting asyncronous option to false and setup the result var out of ajax function:

```
var result = false;

$.ajax(
{
    ...
    async: false,
    ...
    success: function(response)
    {
        ...
        ...
        result = true;
    }
});

return result;
```